# WSO2 IS + kerberos kdc externo

Tags: seguridad, wso2, kerberos

Estoy realizando un proyecto con `WSO2` y me gustaría integrar la autenticación de ticket's de `kerberos` externalizando este. ¿Hay alguna manera?
Sé que el servidor de identidad de `WSO2` incluye un servidor de `kerberos`, pero como digo, me gustaría externalizarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).